# Consultar numero de registros, en base a otra tabla MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Esta consulta no se como hacerla, el problema es el siguiente: Tengo 2 tablas relacionada por `id_empresa`:

> -`Empresas` contiene `id_empresa` y `nombre`
>
> -`Usuarios` contiene `id_usuario`, `id_empresa`  y `nombre`

Tengo 4 Empresas registradas y varios usuarios, necesito una consulta donde me retorne el numero de usuarios de cada empresa

Algo así

```
Empresa 1 :1
Empresa 2 :0
Empresa 3 :2
Empresa 4 :0
```

Intente usar `Count` pero solo me retorna el numero de registros.

Comment: Tienes que contar pero si no los agrupas no te los va a segmentar por empresas, tendrás que usar `group by` como mínimo, y si éste tiene alguna otra condición usar `having`. Si pudieras incluir en tu pregunta lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora mejor, así podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: Para poder responderte correctamente necesitamos el SQL con el que generar esa base de datos, algunos registros de ejemplo (opción Exportar del phpMyAdmin) y que hayas intentando resolver la consulta tú mismo, para lo que tendrás que aportar tu código: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Ánimo que casi lo tienes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer un `JOIN` entre ambas tablas y agrupar por `id_empresa`.

La consulta sería esta:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(e.nombre) AS empresa,
  COUNT(*) AS total_usuarios
FROM empresa e
INNER JOIN usuario u ON e.id_empresa=u.id_empresa
GROUP BY u.id_empresa;
```

Aquí usamos `MAX(e.nombre)` para satisfacer el requerimiento `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, el cual suelo encender siempre en este tipo de consultas, porque de lo contrario MySQL, en su permisividad, deja crear consultas no conformes al estándar SQL cuando se agrupan datos.

#### Fiddle

Aquí te dejo una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/OIB54761)**</kbd>, que puedes probar en línea.

**Creación del esquema**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empresa 
(
    id_empresa       INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre           VARCHAR(100)
 )ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO empresa (nombre) 
    VALUES
    ('Empresa 1'),
    ('Empresa 2'),
    ('Empresa 3'),
    ('Empresa 4');
    
    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario 
(
    id_usuario      INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre          VARCHAR(100),
    id_empresa      INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_empresa) REFERENCES empresa(id_empresa) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE  CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO usuario (nombre,id_empresa) 
    VALUES
    ('Pedro',1),
    ('María',2),
    ('Santiago',3),
    ('Marta',4),
    ('Juan',4),
    ('Sara',2),
    ('José',1);

    
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

---

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT 
  MAX(e.nombre) AS empresa,
  COUNT(*) AS total_usuarios
FROM empresa e
INNER JOIN usuario u ON e.id_empresa=u.id_empresa
GROUP BY u.id_empresa;
```

---

**Resultados:**

```
|   empresa | total_usuarios |
|-----------|----------------|
| Empresa 1 |              2 |
| Empresa 2 |              2 |
| Empresa 3 |              1 |
| Empresa 4 |              2 |
```

---

**P.D.:**

Si quieres que te devuelva `0` en aquellas empresas que no tienen ningún usuario, habría que modificar ligeramente la consulta, usando `LEFT JOIN` y poniendo la columna `u.id_empresa` en el `COUNT`, algo así:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(e.nombre) AS empresa,
  COUNT(u.id_empresa) AS total_usuarios
FROM empresa e
LEFT JOIN usuario u ON e.id_empresa=u.id_empresa
GROUP BY u.id_empresa;
```

Comment: Estas seguro que l max es necesario? que pasa si solo agrupas por el nombre de la empresa, y quitas el max?

Comment: @gbianchi en rextester no me da error, pero en sqlfiddle me dice: *`e.nombre isn't in GROUP BY`* y no funciona la consulta. Se ve que sqlfiddle sigue el estándar SQL92, y rextester el estándar SQL99, [según esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25800677/5587982)... Yo lo que tengo entendido es que, al usar `GROUP BY` las columnas del `SELECT`, si no están en el `GROUP BY`, deben ser únicamente PK o traídas con funciones de agregación, porque de lo contrario el manejador no sabría qué dato presentar en el caso de que haya dos valores iguales.

Comment: No. No tienen que ser pk. Tienen que estar en el select. Vos podes agrupar por cualquier forma. Tu group by deberia se e.nombre y el select e.nombre y deberia andar

Comment: @gbianchi considero que en este caso no sería correcto agrupar por `e.nombre`, no sin saber si esa columna es `UNIQUE` en la tabla. Si hubiera dos empresas con el mismo nombre podría tener resultados irreales. Dos empresas se pueden llamar igual en efecto, si la unicidad dependiese de otros factores como la ciudad, el país, u otros. No considero que sea una columna idónea para agrupar.

Comment: Buen punto en eso. ahi estamos de acuerdo de que depende de los datos.

Comment: Igual guardate que podes agrupar por cualquier campo, no tiene que ser PK, eso es importante...

Comment: Esta consulta funciona casi perfectamente, pero tiene un detalle, si la empresa no tiene usuarios no la regresa en la consulta, cuando si  no tiene debería regresara con un 0

Comment: @rances5171 revisa la consulta al final de la respuesta, donde se contempla la posibilidad de empresas que no tengan usuarios.

Comment: jajaja lo siento estoy algo ciego gracias esa es la respuesta

Comment: @rances5171, no estás ciego... esa parte acabo de agregarla debido a tu comentario. No sabía que te interesaba ese dato.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que estás buscando sería algo parecido a esto:

```
SELECT (SELECT Nombre FROM Empresas WHERE id_empresa = Usuarios.id_empresa) AS Empresa, 
COUNT(id_usuario) AS NumeroUsuarios
FROM Usuarios
GROUP BY id_empresa
```

Esta consulta te devuelve una columna con el nombre de la empresa y la otra columna el número de usuarios de cada empresa.

Answer (score 1):

el modo `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` es solo para cuando se quiere prescindir del `GROUP BY` en una consulta, en conjunto con funciones de agregación (`ANY_VALUE` por ejemplo), pero la forma general, con un SQL ANSI seria:

```
SELECT e.nombre
      ,COUNT(*) AS total_usuarios
FROM   empresa e
INNER  JOIN usuario u ON e.id_empresa=u.id_empresa
GROUP  BY nombre;
```

Comment: Hay alguna forma que me retorne en la lista los que no tienen usuarios ?, es que si no tiene usuarios no retorna le empresa, y yo quiero que aunque no tenga retorne el 0

Comment: un pequeño cambio: SELECT e.nombre
      ,COUNT(u.id_usuario) AS total_usuarios
FROM   empresa e
FULL OUTER JOIN usuario u ON e.id_empresa=u.id_empresa
GROUP  BY nombre;